Nest Js MaxListenersExceededWarning in Commander how to increase limit?
I get this warning
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [Commander]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

when i add more than 6 modules in app.module.ts (i need to add 21 modules). How i can increase this limit and where i need to add emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit of Commander?
And where i need to add code of increasing limit?
I try to use this module
EventEmitterModule.forRoot({
      maxListeners: 100,
      verboseMemoryLeak: true,
    }),

but i still get warning
I get it from bull
(node:15455) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [Commander]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at genericNodeError (node:internal/errors:984:15)
    at wrappedFn (node:internal/errors:538:14)
    at _addListener (node:events:593:17)
    at EventEmitter.addListener (node:events:611:10)
    at /Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/bull/lib/utils.js:39:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.isRedisReady (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/bull/lib/utils.js:17:10)
    at Queue.setWorkerName (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/bull/lib/worker.js:14:8)
    at Queue.setHandler (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:679:8)
    at Queue.process (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:657:8)
    at BullExplorer.handleProcessor (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.explorer.js:91:23)
    at /Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.explorer.js:53:26
    at MetadataScanner.scanFromPrototype (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/metadata-scanner.js:34:31)
    at /Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.explorer.js:50:34
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BullExplorer.explore (/Users/maksimov/Documents/CEO/dashboard/dashboard-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.explorer.js:41:19)



EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
app.use(EventEmitter);

in main.ts
